# Reading three files asynchronously in c#

Tags: c#

I am reading three files asynchronously and writing them into a single file.
The problem is that it writes the content of only the LAST file. Why is that?
My code:Main's class:

```
    public static FileReader filereader1=  new FileReader("file1.txt");
    public static FileReader filereader2 = new FileReader("file2.txt");
    public static FileReader filereader3 = new FileReader("file3.txt");
    public static FileWriter towrite = new FileWriter(writefile.txt");

public static void readFileAsync(object obj)
{
  var filereader = obj as FileReader;
  readf = new ReadFile(filereader.readLine);
  if (filereader!=null)
  {
    while (!filereader.IsFinished)
    {
      IAsyncResult ar = readf.BeginInvoke(new AsyncCallback(myCallback),null);
    }

   }
 }
public static void myCallback(IAsyncResult iar)
{
  AsyncResult ar = (AsyncResult)iar;
  ReadFile readf = (ReadFile)ar.AsyncDelegate;
  string line = readf.EndInvoke(iar);
  writefile.writeLine(line);
 }
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
    readFileAsync(filereader1);
    readFileAsync(filereader2);
    readFileAsync(filereader3);
    Console.ReadKey();
    filereader1.Dispose();
    filereader2.Dispose();
    filereader3.Dispose();
    writefile.Dispose();
```

}
class FileReader:

```
    public static StreamReader toRead { get; set; }
    public string FilePath { get; set; }

    public FileReader(string path)
    {
        FilePath = path;
        toRead = new StreamReader(path);
    }
    public string ReadLine()
    {
        string line=null;

            if (!toRead.EndOfStream)
            {
                line = toRead.ReadLine();
                return line;
            }
            return null;


    }
    public bool IsFinished
    {
        get
        {
            if (toRead != null)
            {
                return toRead.EndOfStream;
            }
            return true;
       }

    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (toRead != null)
        {
            toRead.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

class FileWriter:
      {

```
    public StreamWriter toWrite { get; set; }
    public static object locker = new object();
    public string FilePath { get; set; }

    public FileWriter(string path)
    {
        FilePath = path;
        toWrite = new StreamWriter(path);
    }

    public void writeLine(string line)
    {
        if (toWrite != null)
        {
            lock (locker)
            {
                toWrite.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (toWrite != null)
        {
            toWrite.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `writefile` ?

Comment: writefile is the file I am writting into: StreamWriter writefile=new StreamWriter(path);

Comment: Please format everything into one code block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason that you need to use async callbacks?

If not, try these approaches.

TPL:

```
var tasks = new []
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => File.ReadAllText(@"file1.txt")),
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => File.ReadAllText(@"file2.txt")),
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => File.ReadAllText(@"file3.txt")),
};

Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(tasks, ts =>
{
    var output = @"writefile.txt";
    File.WriteAllText(output, ts[0].Result);
    File.AppendAllText(output, ts[1].Result);
    File.AppendAllText(output, ts[2].Result);
    Console.WriteLine("Done.");
});
```

Microsoft Reactive Framework (Rx):

```
var write = @"writefile.txt";
File.WriteAllText(write, null);

new []
{
    Observable.Start(() => File.ReadAllText(@"file1.txt")),
    Observable.Start(() => File.ReadAllText(@"file2.txt")),
    Observable.Start(() => File.ReadAllText(@"file3.txt")),
}
    .Merge()
    .Subscribe(
        x => File.AppendAllText(write, x),
        () => Console.WriteLine("Done."));
```

Both read the files asynchronously and write the file synchronously (no overwrites!). The TPL solution writes the results in file order. The Rx preserves the order in which the files were finished being read.

---

Your code has a serious issue in these lines:

```
while (!filereader.IsFinished)
{
    IAsyncResult ar = readf.BeginInvoke(new AsyncCallback(myCallback),null);
}
```

It is asynchronously trying to read lines, but it is synchronously trying to determine if you've hit the end of the file. This will try to fire off many asynchronous calls before even the first one reads from the file. This code is never going to work.

The other issue with your code was that the line defining the stream in the `FileReader` class was declared `static`. This needed to be defined as such:

```
public StreamReader toRead { get; set; }
```

Now I did rejig the code to produce this which worked fairly well:

```
public static void readFileAsync(FileReader filereader)
{
    var readf = new ReadFile(filereader.ReadLine);
    Action<IAsyncResult> callBack = null;
    callBack = iar =>
    {
        var line = readf.EndInvoke(iar);
        writefile.writeLine(line);
        if (!filereader.IsFinished)
        {
            readf.BeginInvoke(new AsyncCallback(callBack), null);
        }
    };
    if (!filereader.IsFinished)
    {
        readf.BeginInvoke(new AsyncCallback(callBack), null);
    }
}
```

This worked by only invoking a new read once the previous one had finished.

I also did a complete redesign and changed the asynchronicity to be file-base, not line-based. This worked too:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var writefile = new FileWriter(@"writefile.txt"))
        {
            Action<string> readAndWrite= fn =>
            {
                using (var fr = new FileReader(fn))
                {
                    while (!fr.IsFinished)
                    {
                        writefile.writeLine(fr.ReadLine());
                    }
                }
            };

            AsyncCallback callBack = ar => { };

            var ar1 = readAndWrite.BeginInvoke(@"file1.txt", callBack, null);
            var ar2 = readAndWrite.BeginInvoke(@"file2.txt", callBack, null);
            var ar3 = readAndWrite.BeginInvoke(@"file3.txt", callBack, null);

            WaitHandle.WaitAll(new[]
            {
                    ar1.AsyncWaitHandle,
                    ar2.AsyncWaitHandle,
                    ar3.AsyncWaitHandle,
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully these suggestions help.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer, but my assingment's requests are using an asynchron delegate(like i used readf: public delegate string ReadFile()) and the files must be read line by line(that is why I have readline function in class FileReader).

Comment: @AnaMaria - Your code isn't reading line by line. It seems to only call each `readFileAsync` once for each file. So it must be reading the whole file in one go or reading only the first line. Do you have class definitions for `FileReader` and the `writefile` variable?

Comment: I added FileReader class definition, above. writefile it's a FileWriter whose pattern it's pretty much the same as FileReader's. Practically writefile it's the file I am writting into. I also tried a Main approach like:  ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(readFileAsync, filereader1) instead of just calling readFileAsync.

Comment: @AnaMaria - I hate to say it, but your code is getting more bizarre the more you post. Is there any chance you can post the complete assignment request? If not, then the complete code would be nice. You've kind of given snippits so far and there's clearly code that is missing that is relevant.

Comment: I corrected above. The asignment is as I said: reading from 3 files(filereader1/2/3/), line by line, asynchronously and writting contents into a single file(wirtefile). In my code I made a class for reading(FileReader) and a class for writting(FileWriter).

Comment: @AnaMaria - I've answered your question more directly.

Comment: Well that worked as I wanted, Thankyou very much. I just learned this days about asynchronicity, so I don't really know how to think in depth of this concept; for now. I got one more question: it is because of asynchronicity or why the written lines in writefile are mixed; don't keep the order? Is there a way I could sincronize this? I tried, before, using lock, but did not work...or maybe I do not know how to use lock.

Comment: @AnaMaria - When you say they don't keep the order do you mean that lines from one or more of the source files are switched around (i.e. line 8 & line 9 from "file1.txt" are written in the wrong order) or do you mean that the lines from the three files are mixed in together (but still in the correct order from the original files)?

Comment: lines of one file are mixed with the lines of the other file in the writefile; so writefile becomes unreadable. Most of the times writefile it's ok, but I "played" the program almost 10 times until I got the result...

Comment: @AnaMaria - That's because you are reading each line asynchronously. You should use one of the first options I gave you. Much simpler and you can control the writing output much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Make writefile a single instance and apply aync lock when writing contents.

```
public static void myCallback(IAsyncResult iar)
{
  AsyncResult ar = (AsyncResult)iar;
  ReadFile readf = (ReadFile)ar.AsyncDelegate;
  string line = readf.EndInvoke(iar);
  lock(obj)
  {
    writefile.writeLine(line);
    successCount++;
  }
 }
private static object obj = new object();
private static int successCount = 0;
static void Main(string[] args)
 {
    readFileAsync(filereader1);
    readFileAsync(filereader2);
    readFileAsync(filereader3);
    while(Console.ReadKey())
    {
        if(successCount == 3)
        {
            filereader1.Dispose();
            filereader2.Dispose();
            filereader3.Dispose();
            writefile.Dispose();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you mean using singleton?

Comment: @AnaMaria Singleton not a must. I'm not sure whether the the 3 readFileAsync are sharing the same "writefile". If yes, just to wrap writefile.writeLine with a lock statement is fine. Please see my updated answer with sample code.

Comment: I get youre update, I used lock before (to write AND read, but also separately) and still, same result. I also observed that if I execute just one call,let's say readFileAsync(filereader1) and comment other two,the result is the same: reads and writes from file3 but filereader1 uses file1. how is that possible? And yes, writefile is shared. All three files(file1.txt,file2.txt,file3.txt) must have their content written in the same file which is writefile.txt

Comment: filereader1/2/3 are defined using class FileReader which is listed above.I also have the FileWriter class for writefile, which has pretty much the same pattern like FileReader.